# negative binomial GLM with time elapsed as a predictor

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, negative-binomial-distribution

Suppose you have a response variable, number of transactions a customer makes in the 24 hour period following acquisition, which follows a negative binomial distribution. Let's call the response *trans*.

Now it's easy to model the number of transactions the customer makes in this immediate 24 hour period, or *trans*, using Library(MASS) in r and running a negative binomial GLM. I can get a nice fit by thoughtful selection of predictors.

Now I want to model the number of transactions a customer makes in *any* 24 hour period as a function of the number of days elapsed since the customer was acquired (call this predictor *t*). Empirically, as time elapsed increases, the 24 hour transaction rate decreases, although the rate of decrease is a decreasing function of time.  Plugging number of days elapsed, or *t*, into the aforementioned negative binomial GLM runs in to all sorts of problems. I can get a good fit by adding a quadratic term *t^2* but I cannot project beyond the number of days in the data set without getting illogical results; clearly adding a quadratic term is just curve fitting without capturing the underlying relationship of 24 hour transaction rates vs time elapsed since acquisition.

Is there any better way to approach this problem? I will add more details if this is unclear.

Comment: You might find the approaches described in the following Q&A helpful... http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24047/almon-model-for-distributed-time-series-analysis

Comment: Thank you, this gave me the idea of looking at some simultaneous equations estimation techniques popular for use with macroeconomic research.

Comment: Another option would be to look at other transformations of t.  Adding a quadratic term is often problematic for extrapolation, but a logarithm transform or some other method might give you a decreasing rate of decrease without the same problems.

Comment: This paper by Bruce Hardie on projecting customer retention clearly explains the trouble with traditional parametric methods:

Comment: link to aforementioned paper: http://www.brucehardie.com/papers/021/sbg_2006-05-30.pdf The change in my 24 hour transaction rate is largely a function of customer retention over time. Perhaps I could incorporate the survival function mentioned in this paper into my original model.